# Sqlite Error - "Insertion Failure: unable to open database file"

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm using NSTimer to call the below function every second and and pass the values for activityType and activityConfidence using parameters. After some successful insertions I'm getting an error "unable to open database file"

```
-(void)tableInsertionFunction:(NSString *)activityType confidenceIs:(NSString *)activityConfidence 
{

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];
    databasePath =  [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mainSDK.db"];
    dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, & demoDB) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *insertStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO activityTable ( activityType , activityConfidence) VALUES ('%@' , '%@' )",activityType, activityConfidence];

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertStatement UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(demoDB, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"Insertion Successful");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Insertion Failure: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(demoDB));
        }

        sqlite3_close(demoDB);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do so many read/write operations keep the database open and close it at the end. I.e. open it once and close it once when done with the ViewController

Comment: To be precise you are getting `Insertion Failure: unable to open database file`?

Comment: @trojanfoe , yes I'm getting the same error

Comment: OK, as already mentioned: keep the database open and all the time the database is open you can store that prepared statement away to save time.  You will have to use bind variables, however, rather than formatting the statement as you currently do.  It will be faster and much more secure, however.

Comment: As per suggestions above, I have kept my database open and now the program is running for some extra time. But after having 250 successful insertions I'm getting the same error again.